# Spark.ml DataFrame containing SparseVector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a spark.ml `DataFrame` that contains many columns, each of these columns containing a `SparseVector` per row. I would like to apply `MultivariateStatisticalSummary.colStats` to each column, and `colStats` signature is:

```
def colStats(X: RDD[Vector]): MultivariateStatisticalSummary
```

which seems perfect... except that I can't seem to `select` a column from that `DataFrame` and get it to be a `RDD[Vector]`. Here is my attempt:

```
val df: DataFrame = data.select(shardId)
val col = df.as[(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)].rdd
val s: MultivariateStatisticalSummary = Statistics.colStats(col)
```

which doesn't compile with the message (in Scala):

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
val col = df.as[(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)].rdd
```

I also tried:

```
 val df = data.select(shardId)
 val col: RDD[Vector] = df.map(x => x.asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector])
 val s: MultivariateStatisticalSummary = Statistics.colStats(col)
```

which fails at runtime with error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
```

How can I bridge the gap between `DataFrame` and `colStats`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after all:

```
 val df = data.select(shardId)
 val col: RDD[Vector] = df.map { _.get(0).asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] }
 val s: MultivariateStatisticalSummary = Statistics.colStats(col)
```

The trick was only to extract the first element of each row before casting it.